# How to handle an .fsproj file on the command line?

Tags: command-line, f#, fedora

I would like to use exercism to solve F# exercises. I do this on Fedora.

Exercism downloads an `.fsproj` file. How can I handle it from the command line?

Is there something like the command `make` for a `Makefile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the [dotnet SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) installed.

`dotnet build X.fsproj` should restore and build the project.
`dotnet run X.fsproj` will run it. You can also run it against a *.sln* file.
`dotnet test X.fsproj` will execute your unit tests. Note: Here it reported I only had 1 test file (wrong) but picked up all my tests.

To test if you have it installed and on your PATH, execute: `dotnet --version`. The current version is 3.1.
`dotnet --help` will show you all possible commands.

Of interest may be that F# Interactive is now baked into the SDK.
`dotnet fsi` to enter interactive environment.
`#quit;;` to exit interactive environment.
This allows you to play with F# right in the command line.

Comment: Is this possible in Mono?

Comment: For mono, use `MSBuild x.fsproj`

Comment: @Gergely I recommend not using Mono unless you are required to do so (e.g., Xamarin support).